# Convert Webm or m4a file to mp3

Tags: java, android, type-conversion, mp3, webm

Is There any way to convert webm and m4a files to mp3 In android studio.
because changing the file extension makes  it seem like mp3 file but it is unseekable after changing extension...the webm and m4a files only contain audio.

Comment: Do you mean to implement this function programmatically using Java? If not, check this https://convertio.co/m4a-mp3/

Comment: yes programmatically using Java..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with the implementation of https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioConverter easily.

You need to import it to your project using

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioConverter:0.0.8'
}
```

and as per the github page you will need to compile com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg dependencie also.

Comment: i tried adding the dependency (implementation 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioConverter:0.0.8') ...gradle sync is failing.Am i implementing the library wrong ??

Comment: @AdanNelson Updated the post

Comment: thanks for your answer but i used ffmpeg instead..should i post my code or just mark this answer completed ? im new here so i dont know the rules..

Comment: @AdanNelson You may post your own answer If it is related to the topic or else mark this topic as solution and If this helped you then Kindly upvote it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fucntion for ffmpeg i have used..... i simply imported the ffmpeg library..

```
private void calculate(final String title , final String Type, final int id){
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(new String[]{"-i",Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_MUSIC)+"/"+title+"."+Type, Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_MUSIC)+"/"+title+".mp3"}, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.d("ffmpegevent", "onProgress: "+message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.d("ffmpegevent", "onProgress: "+message);
                Log.d("ffmpegevent", "onFailure: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.d("ffmpegevent", "onSuccess: ");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d("ffmpegevent", "onProgress: Finished");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    }

}
```